# Is there a SoftInputMode workaround to show whole dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have a `DialogFragment` with two `EditText` fields and another field with an `ImageView` to increment its value underneath these, they all live in a `ScrollView`.

The problem is neither adjust mode for the <kbd>soft keyboard</kbd> shows my entire `DialogFragment` at once, despite there being space.

`adjustResize` causes the `ScrollView` to resize and hide the bottom row. `adjustpan` keeps the `ScrollView` size intact but the <kbd>soft keyboard</kbd> overlaps the bottom row.

Removing the `ScrollView` means either option causes the keyboard to overlap.

What I would like is for the DialogFragment to move up the screen without resizing. Can I make that happen? Ideally I'd like to keep the `ScrollView` in my `Layout` to better support very small screens.

[image: adjustPan] [image: adjustResize] [image: The result I'd like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found was to change the window options for the dialog fragment itself. Obviously on a smaller screen this will still be an issue so I am still looking for a better answer.

```
@Override
@NonNull
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //I was using android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar for another issue
    //but I don't think the theme makes any difference to how the window is laid out 
    //that is relevant to the below code
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    ... //Do your usual stuff here
    dialog.getWindow().setContentView(...);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP; //this is the important part
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    return dialog;

}
```